# How can I modify Powershell script to extract latest zip file, and extract the files within folder

Tags: powershell

Can someone please help me to modify the Powershell script below to extract the most recent zip file (instead of filename 20230306), and also extract the contents of the folder within?

```
powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& { $shell = New-Object -COM Shell.Application; $target = $shell.NameSpace('C:\TEMP\TXT_SOURCES'); $zip = $shell.NameSpace('C:\TEMP\TXT_SOURCES\20230306.zip'); $target.CopyHere($zip.Items(), 16); }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain a bit more about what you've tried and what you mean?
"extract the contents of the folder within"... is something zipped within your zip?

Perhaps:

```
Expand-Archive -Path (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\TEMP\TXT_SOURCES' -Filter '*.zip' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).FullName -DestinationPath 'C:\TEMP\TXT_SOURCES'
```